# Java - Extracting sub-sequences from a character file

Tags: java

I have a character file of 1.99 GB. Now, I want to extract millions of sub-sequences from that file randomly for example from position 90 to 190, 10 to 110, 50000 to 50100 etc. (each of 100 characters long). Can anybody help me how can I do that in a nice way.

NB: I have not enough memory to take the whole file into memory.

Comment: Are the subsequences in order? Do they overlap?  Can you hold all of the subsequence ranges (not the content, just the begin/end points) in memory?  Very roughly, what percentage of the file is in a subsequence?

Comment: @EdStaub, "Are the subsequences in order?" - No, random. "Do they overlap?" may be. "Can you hold all of the subsequence ranges (not the content, just the begin/end points) in memory?" - I have that much memory but as I need the sub sequences soon, I can't wait for that.

Comment: Sorry, not following - wait for what?

Comment: @EdStaub, wait to collect all begin/end points.

Answer (score 2):

Split the file into several files of fixed size (say 16K each).

When reading char n, do n / filesize to get the file. Use n % filesize to get starting character in file. For reading in the file tail, you can either add extra logic and read the next file, or just add to each file the following 100 characters (and duplicate them in the next file).

Of course there is just the option of using just the original file and open/do a `seek` each time. But I am not sure about the performance of it, and it can vary wildly with different OS.

Option 2: Generate a lot of the random indexes and order them. Then just do one sweep of the file (RandomAccessFile or FileInputStream) and get all the chains. It will minimize HD time, the issue will be controlling the memory needed to store the indexes / time needed to order them. Also there is the added complexity of the case when a character belongs to two or more chains.

Comment: I think it in that way, but that may be quite expensive way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) - it allows to seek file to a random position and read needed amount of characters.

Comment: Is that supports 1.99 GB file ?

Comment: @Arpssss It's a bit smaller then 2Gb - so yes. If your file is bigger than 2Gb - there might be a problem (see here http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4116672)

Comment: I have doubts as how is RandomAccessFile implemented on top of FS. V.g., on a FAT it would still read all the blocks to get to the desired one; it would ease use but would not offer a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the needed subsequences by starting index.

Now start walking through them.  Use RandomAccessFile to grab a block of disk starting at the start-point of the next subsequence needed.

The size of the block depends on your hit ratio (how much of the rest of the block is likely to be useful) - the higher the hit ratio, the bigger the block should be (up to a point, of course).  You might consider looking ahead in the subsequence list and adapting the blocksize accordingly.  Pull all the subsequences you can out of the block.  Repeat until done.

I don't understand what the issue is with files > 2GB noted elsewhere.